# Mostrar tabla ordenada

Tags: python

Buenas tardes para todos.

Debo realizar un programa en python que al seleccionar una opción, muestre los datos de una tabla (offices), de la base de datos (classicmodels) en este caso.

El programa es orientado a objetos y con pymysql.

Tengo lo siguiente:
[image: codigo]

Este es el resultado ordenado:
[image: imagen offices ordenada]

Pero el resultado que obtengo del programa es el siguiente:
[image: imagen offices desordenada]

Quiero saber como puedo ordenar los datos de la tabla.
Muchas gracias a las personas que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Agrega directamente la clausula `ORDER BY`  al `SELECT`, indicando las columnas por la cuales deseas el ordenar

Comment: Y por otro lado, por favor, no uses imágenes para mostrarnos el código.

Answer (score 0):

Para que salga ordenado, debes añadir la clausula ORDER BY NombreColumna si quieres que sea descendiente, añade DESC, por el contrario, si lo dejas vacío como si pones ASC será ascendente.

```
registros == """
  SELECT 
  * 
  FROM offices 
  ORDER BY state DESC """
```

Otra opción es leerlo con un pandas de esta manera:

```
# en la cabecera agrega el import de pandas
import pandas as pd 

sql = registros == """
  SELECT 
  * 
  FROM offices 
  ORDER BY state DESC """
generator_df = pd.read_sql(sql=query, con=conncection)

print(generator_df)
```